# Solution of nonhomogeneous problem using semigroup of linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let $X$ be a complex Hilbert space; and let $A:D(A)\subset X \to X$ be a $\mathbb C-$linear operator. Assume that $A$ is self-adjoint(so that $D(A)$ is a dense subset of $X$) and that $A\leq 0$ (i.e., $(Ax,x)\leq 0$ for all $x\in D(A)$).\
Since $A$ is self-adjoint, $iA:D(A)\subset X \to X$ defined by $(iA)x:=iAx$ for $x\in D(A)$ is also $\mathbb C-$linear and is skew-adjoint.
In particular, $iA$ generates the group of isometries $\{\mathcal{T}(t)\}_{t\in \mathbb R}$ on $X.$ We deduce easily from the skew-adjointness of $iA$ that,
$$\mathcal{T}(t)^{\ast}=\mathcal{T}(-t), \forall t \in \mathbb R.$$

For every $x\in X$ and every $f\in C([0,T], X)$ (where $T\in \mathbb R$), there exists a unique solution of the problem
$$ (NH)
\begin{cases}
u\in C([0, T], X) \cap C^{1}([0, T], (D(A))'),\\
i\frac{du}{dt}+\bar{A}u+f=0,\\
u(0)=x.
\end{cases}
$$

**My Question is**:

> How to show, $u\in C([0, T], X) $ is a solution of the above problem $(NH)$ if and only if $u$ satisfies
>   $$u(t)=\mathcal{T}(t)x+i\int_{0}^{t}\mathcal{T}(t-s)f(s) ds;$$
>   for all $t\in [0, T].$

**Note**. For more detail of the above problem see "Semilinear Schr\"odinger Equations" by Thierray Cazenave, section 1.6

Thanks,

**Edit**: We put, $(D(A))'=$ The dual of $D(A);$ and $A$ can be extended to a self adjoint operator $\bar{A}$ on $(\mathcal{D}(A))'$ with domain $X.$ We note,  $\bar{A}|_{D(A)}=A.$

Comment: There are a couple of symbols you don't explain: $(\mathcal{D}(A))'$ and $\overline{A}$.

Comment: @T.A.E.; thanks, I have edited it.

Comment: What did you get by taking the inner-product of the desired equation with an element of $\mathcal{D}(A)$?